# Is it right to use "is mixed" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, middle-voice

> The smoke of the factories, ships, and machines ____(mix) with the early rays of the sun to create a sort of beauty that is "both surprising and charming".

I filled in the blank with its passive voice "is mixed", but the answer read "mixes". Could English native speakers tell me which one is more proper and why?

The whole regulative passage reads:

> The masterpiece imagery presents a focus on a calm feeling of a foggy seaside scene Slightly below the center of the painting, in a small rowboat with two unclear figures floats in the bay. The early morning sun is pictured rising over the foggy harbor with ships and other various boats at port. The shadows of the boats and figures and the reflection of the sunrise can be seen on the water surface.The smoke of the factories, ships, and machines ____(mix) with the early rays of the sun to create a sort of beauty that is "both surprising and charming".

Comment: I think this depends entirely on the context of the sentence. Is your italicised sentence the entirety of the question? Is it based on a paragraph you haven't given here?

Comment: There seem to be some errors in the passage you have transcribed (using rising?). To say that the smoke 'is mixed' with the sun's rays could suggest that someone is deliberately mixing them together, when in fact it's a process that is happening naturally.

Comment: Please provide the source.

Comment: It's entirtely a stylistic choice whether to use ***mixes, is mixing,*** or some other verb in the cited context. Personally, I might use ***interweaves*** or [some other "synonym".](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/interweaves)

Comment: Unless the hand of God or the wind or some other agent is stirring the smoke and rays, *mixed* is a past participle adjective — not a passive voice construction.

Comment: @KateBunting, it is true that the process is **depicted** in the picture as happening naturally, but that depiction is created deliberately by the painter, so somebody could argue that, in a way, it is the painter that mixed them together. I agree that 'mixes' is better, but the possibility of arguing either way makes this ill suited for a test on which all answers must be treated as either definitely right or definitely wrong.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Middle voice constructions need better coverage on this site. Are we describing the reality, or the imagery? Is the effect being regarded as a simple attribute of a painting long since fixed (paintings don't have volition), or are we considering the way the artist pulled it off (artists do have volition). Are we blurring the distinction between the image and the real, transporting ourselves to an imaginary harbor, or taking a clinical view of the painting?

Comment: @jsw29 Agreed that this *example* is a poorly set test question, but the OP's question of "which one is more proper and why", or at least "which one is more proper and when" is answerable.

Comment: This appears to be some poor plagiarism (w/a misquote) of an analysis of Monet's Impression, Sunrise. Note the obvious error: the "in" before the subject "a small rowboat" in the 2nd sentence. (BTW, you're missing a period after the 1st sentence.) And it s/b "seductive" [Tucker, P], not "charming" (the misquote). That should have that question omitted, but it's a painting—the scene is in the here and now: *boat floats, smoke mixes* or "emissions…mix" [Yurasits, J]. More importantly, it's not a tequila sunrise; meaning matters. Also, pay attention to what follows (*mix(es)…to create*).

Comment: https://blogs.longwood.edu/incite/2012/01/30/analysis-of-claude-monet%E2%80%99s-impression-sunrise/#_ftn4

Comment: *Impression, Sunrise*

Comment: @HippoSawrUs That link does not work for me. [Here](https://blogs.longwood.edu/incite/2012/01/30/analysis-of-claude-monet/#_ftn4) is an edited link (for some reason the '/'s became '%'s..). (However, it did work a few minutes later, so maybe it is my browser.)

Comment: @Joachim - I've seen a few versions of that description online, on sites selling prints of that painting and on a quiz site. Maybe that's where the tester got the idea, but their version is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

'Is mixed' is better. As Kate Bunting mentions as well, the process is passive, hence 'mixing' comes across as a little odd.

However, I wouldn't use the verb 'mix' at all, as it suggests intent. A better option would be '[mingle](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mingle)':

> to become mixed, blended, or united

(Disclaimer: I'm not a native English speaker.)

Comment: But the process isn't passive - and that's precisely the trouble. Unlike passive, the agent is totally surpressed. This is middle voice. *Mix* can appear in active, passive, or middle voice constructions, similar to *melt* and *freeze*.

Comment: @PhilSweet — *mix* is "middle voice" only in e.g. *Smoke mixes with rays.* With *is mixed*, it's either passive or adjectival, depending on context.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Exactly, and only the construction associated with middle voice matches the pragmatics of the situation - studying the imagery of a painting of a harbor. The sentence deals with how an effect was rendered by the artist, not how it was concocted or manifested in real life. The effect is an attribute of the painting itself. And yes, I'm probably splitting hairs a bit here, but I wouldn't use the other when talking about a painting. If I was talking about the actual scene, then I would *really* be splitting hairs, because I certainly wouldn't feel anything was strange in conversation.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that in discussions of imagery; critics, docents and others are often trying to blur the distinction between the image and the real - trying to get you to imagine you are really there. On the other hand, I spend rather too much time trying to help people sort out the differences and understand how simple attributes of models are not simple attributes of reality. So I may be working at cross-purposes here.

Comment: @PhilSweet — I would call *Smoke mixes with rays* a perfectly natural example of the middle voice using the narrative present. It puts us in the scene. The problem with the passage, if there is one, is that it flips between narration in the narrative present and explanation in the passive voice: *the boat floats*, *the smoke mixes*, but *the sun is pictured*, *the shadows can be seen*.

Comment: And that is why the choice for the ______ is unclear.

Comment: I actually hadn't considered the fact that it is indeed about the - very active - process of painting (ironically, since I am a painter). I think you are completely right in that last assessment, @TinfoilHat, and just the general discussion clarifying it. Thanks, all!

Comment: This answer doesn't address the quiz answer (*mixes*). BTW, the sample is flawed, poorly paraphrased, etc., so I only commented on it.